# ZSH Completion colors and OS X

Tags: macos, shell, colors, zsh

Consider this minimal .zshrc :

```
export CLICOLOR=1;
export LSCOLORS=exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad; # It is the default value on OSX, so this line can be omitted

autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors 'exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad'
```

On OS X, `ls` uses colors if `CLICOLOR` is set to TRUE and the colors used are in `LSCOLORS` which default value is  `exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad`.

Doing a `ls` will print directories in blue. But when doing `cd + TAB`, ZSH will propose completions with directories in red and in bold.
What is the problem and how can I have the same colors for ZSH completion and `ls`?

Comment: why do you need  `autoload -Uz compinit` etc. ? Can't you just have `zstyle ...` ?

Answer (score 35):

You need to read the instructions carefully: `zsh` knows how to handle `LS_COLORS`, which is the GNU/Linux variant of `ls` color configuration, but you use OSX's/BSD's `LSCOLORS`. They are *very* different, and it appears `zsh` doesn't know how to handle the latter.

`LSCOLORS` example for red output:

```
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

`LS_COLORS` example for red output:

```
di=31;41:ln=31;41:so=31;41:pi=31;41:ex=31;41:bd=31;41:cd=31;41:su=31;41:sg=31;41:tw=31;41:ow=31;41:
```

---

Use e.g. [this tool](http://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/) ([also on Github](https://github.com/ggreer/lscolors)) to create a nice color scheme, or recreate the one you use, copy its output for *Linux `LS_COLORS`*, then use the following to set the colors:

```
# between quotation marks is the tool output for LS_COLORS
export LS_COLORS="di=31;41:ln=31;41:so=31;41:pi=31;41:ex=31;41:bd=31;41:cd=31;41:su=31;41:sg=31;41:tw=31;41:ow=31;41:"
zstyle ':completion:*:default' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
```