# ls not using the LS_COLORS environment variable

Tags: bash, colors, environment-variables, ls

I am using the configuration below for `ls`. I have changed the `$LS_COLORS` variable to display directories as cyan colored using `di=01;36`. However, when I run `ls`, directories show in purple.

If I run `echo $LS_COLORS` I see the correct variable. It seems as though ls is simply ignoring `$LS_COLORS`. What am I missing?

```
# Detect which `ls` flavor is in use
if ls --color > /dev/null 2>&1; then # GNU `ls`
    colorflag="--color"
else # OS X `ls`
    colorflag="-G"
fi

# List all files colorized in long format
alias l="ls -l ${colorflag}"

# List all files colorized in long format, including dot files
alias la="ls -la ${colorflag}"

# List only directories
alias lsd='ls -l ${colorflag} | grep "^d"'

# Always use color output for `ls`
alias ls="command ls ${colorflag}"
export LS_COLORS='no=00:fi=00:di=01;36:ln=01;34:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.ogg=01;35:*.mp3=01;35:*.wav=01;35:'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OS X uses a different variable, `LSCOLORS`, with a completely different format. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/314459/22317) for more information and a conversion tool.